# Website multiple views configured similarly

Tags: view

I have been having messaged like these from Google:

Redundant Views
You have multiple views in property Anglais-Formation-Question that are configured similarly. Consider removing unneeded views to keep your configuration lean and easy to manage.

I am not sure what to do, I did put a canonical to tell Google this is no spam or fraud, but I keep the same message coming back.

Can you please help or explain and do I need to do anything about this?

Emmanuel